# jQuery hover effect doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Today I tried to use jQuery hover effect, but it didn't work as well as I expected.
When I hover on div element to show other div element insted of 1st div element, they are both starting flashing.

The JS code is following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.section-text').hide();


$('.section-item-portal').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.section-text').fadeIn();
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

$('.section-item-portal').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.section-text').fadeOut();
    $(this).fadeIn();
}); });
```

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/DXRxA/6/

Please help to give solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, when you hide the element you bound the mouseleave event on, then you raise that event. Because  the mouse is _not_ hovering that element any more, since it is not there any more. This is why you get the "loop effect" you can see.

Comment: That is because you are calling .fadeOut() on the element's mouseenter, which cause the element to be hidden by setting its display to none. When it becomes hidden, its mouseleave event triggers which causes the .section-text to be hidden and your .section-item-portal element to become visible. Which triggers its mouseenter. This cycle repeats endlessly. What is the behaviour you want?

Comment: I understood that @arkascha , but is it possible to do that in other way?

Comment: Well, don't remove the element! Make it opaque and place the other stuff _below_ it for example. Then you don't even have to fade _that_.

Comment: Anyway it will flash @arkascha

Comment: No, it won't: http://jsfiddle.net/o09j2yca/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to animate `opacity` instead - that will keep the element still occupying its original space when it becomes invisible, while if you do a fadeOut, it will get `display: none` which creates that undesired jumping effect you're getting.

(think `display:none` vs. `visibility:hidden`)

See the solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ow6o9n1t/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.section-text').hide();

    
    $('.section-item-portal').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.section-text').fadeIn();
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0});
    });

    $('.section-item-portal').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.section-text').fadeOut();
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
    });

});
```

```css
.section-item-portal {
    position: relative;
    width: 237px;
    height: 137px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.section-text {
 position: absolute;
 width: 217px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.53); 
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-item-portal">
   
</div> <div class="section-text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, </div>
```

---

UPDATE

Since you said you want elements to replace each other, here is a plain CSS solution for that (of course, it would work the same way with JS, if you really want it that way):

```css
.section-item-portal {
    position: relative;
    width: 237px;
    height: 137px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
    z-index: 1;
}
.section-item-portal:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
.section-text {
 position: absolute;
 width: 217px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.53); 
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
    top: 8px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-item-portal">
   
</div> <div class="section-text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, </div>
```

---

Container version (selectable background text):

```css
.section-item-portal {
    position: relative;
    width: 237px;
    height: 137px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
    z-index: 1;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container:hover .section-item-portal {
    opacity: 0;
}
.container:hover .section-text {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
}
.section-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 217px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 8px;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="section-item-portal"></div>
    <div class="section-text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet,</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this version other div element changes its position. I wnat to apear it insted of 1st div element.
It can be without fading effect. http://jsfiddle.net/DXRxA/8/

Comment: Oh, that's what you want... Here is a plain CSS solution, no JS needed: http://jsfiddle.net/x014w6dj/

Comment: In this case I can't select the text which is inserted into div :(

Comment: Then you can do something like this, using a container: http://jsfiddle.net/e250p1dm/